# Zoom in on child element PixiJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, zooming, pixi.js

I am trying to create an interface using PIXI JS where I have one main canvas i.e. the stage. After that I have a graphics element as a child to the stage. On clicking the graphic element I want to be able to zoom in on the element so that it fills up 80% of my canvas. My main goal is to have multiple elements and on clicking each of them the canvas zooms in and only that element is visible.

What I have done so far:

```
    this.renderer = this.PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, {
        transparent: true,
        anitalias: true
    });
    this.stage = new this.PIXI.Container();
    this.graphics = new this.PIXI.Graphics();
    this.graphics.beginFill(0x2F7455);
    this.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 75, 50);
    this.graphics.endFill();
    this.graphics.interactive = true;
    this.graphics.click = function (){
        self.animate = true;
        self.grow();
        console.log("I WAS CLICKED");
    }
    this.stage.addChild(this.graphics);

    animation() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animation.bind(this));
        this.renderer.render(this.stage);
    }

    grow() {
        this.stage.pivot.x = this.graphics.width / 2;
        this.stage.pivot.y = this.graphics.height / 2;
        if (this.stage.scale.x < 20) {
            this.stage.scale.x = (this.stage.scale.x * 1.25).toFixed(1);
        }
        if (this.stage.scale.y < 20) {
            this.stage.scale.y = (this.stage.scale.y * 1.25).toFixed(1);
        }
    }
```

So on clicking the graphics element the canvas zooms in. But it's not what I want and I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic that will help me achieve what I want.

Anyone has any ideas on the approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

when asking something special like this you should always create a demonstration on plnkr.co or codepen so that the audience can quickly try out what you have done so far. This will lower the barrier for people to help you.

Regarding your problem. You need to know what size you want to achieve (the stage size), you want to know what size your object has (bounding box) and then you can calculate how much you have to resize. This would be the value 1.25 you just have hardcoded.

You also have to think about what you want to do when the object has another ratio (width vs. height) as the stage. Cut off, fit in or stretch ? This is the idiomatic way.

I also recommend you that you read through the sources of the [pixi camera js library](https://github.com/georgiee/lab-pixicam/blob/d9e8319c13dac4053299007716a666f696959b1e/src/camera.js). You will quickly notice that I worked with matrix multiplications.

Don't let this fear you but encourage you to learn something new. Matrix calculations is the key for being very flexible here and useful in so many other areas of programming.

Good luck.

Comment: The graphics is just a rectangle, once zoomed in I want it to be the size of the window (the renderer).